# Faking socket.io events in browser

Tags: javascript, socket.io, mocha.js, socket.io-1.0

I'm trying to test client side code, which uses socket.io, with mocha. Is there a way to fake/trigger events manually without actually using a test socket.io server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular at front-end ? Take a look at some [socket.io-mock](https://github.com/nullivex/angular-socket.io-mock/blob/master/angular-socket.io-mock.js).

Comment: Actually just plain javascript, but that script solved it. Was thinking too hard, just stub out the emitter methods. Thanks!